# While converting Hexadecimal to ASCII characters I am getting Boxes and unrecognized Symbols

Tags: hex, ascii, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

When I am Converting Hexadecimal Numbers to their ASCII Characters some are coming in boxes with numbers and question marks sort of. I want them to be converted in ASCII Characters.

I have tried converting them to hexa but It is going proper results in hexa but not in %c

```
printf("\nKey Algorithm String: ");
for(i = 80; i<=105; i++)
{       
printf("%c", packet[i]);
}
```

I am Getting  A������T1^�d;���F=D  I want this A.. .....T1^.d;....F =D

Comment: What are the hexadecimal values of the characters that becomes �?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not pure ASCII, that's why you're getting those "weird symbols". ASCII uses the lowest 7 bits with the highest bit always in 0, so it's in range 0-127 but your data is probably in the range 0-255 so you need to know how to interpret these other values.

The alternatives are to ignore all ASCII characters or to decode them correctly.

If you want to just ignore them, filtering out the character that are higher than 127 should be enough. Something similar to this:

```
printf("\nKey Algorithm String: ");
for(i = 80; i <= 105; i++)
{     
    if(packet[i] < 128)  
        printf("%c", packet[i]);
    else
        printf(".");
}
```

If you want to correctly print the rest of the characters, you need to know the charset being used. Most likely it's utf-8 or Latin1 (cp1252). Once you know what it is you can write a decoder yourself or searching for one to use (I'd recommend the latter).

See
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/